# When to use the Stack<T> collection in C#?

Tags: c#, data-structures

I do understand how `Stack()` and `Stack<T>` works, but I really can't see any scenarios where an array, `List<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>` isn't a better and easier choice.

Can anyone provide me a real world example of the use of `Stack<T>`?

Comment: Precisely when you want to enforce that your collection is manipulated like a stack, which List cannot guarantee. IEnumerable is a completely different thing.

Comment: Alright. Can you provide me an example of a scenario where I want the stack behavior?

Comment: hmm `Stack<T>`'s functionality really seems like a subset of `List<T>`, so I agree it doesn't seem like the most useful collection. Enforcing stack behavior is only necessary if it is exposed publicly. But it that case it's usually a better idea to expose some kind of wrapper over the internal collection, so it doesn't really seem very useful for that either. So I'd certainly see use for a `IStack<T>` interface, but not so much for a plain collection class `Stack<T>`.

Comment: <troll>you should use `Stack<T>` when `T` is a value type, because value types live on the stack.</troll>

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ideally you use, or create as needed, classes that reflect how things work in the real world, the things you are modeling in code. Such classes give us a level of abstraction so we can code in terms of what we are modeling/simulating. Additionally when coding some complex thing, using a familiar paradigm helps. To wit: Oh, this Fuzzinator class uses a Stack. I know what a stack is and how it works.

Second, that higher-level-of-abstraction class gives us code that works (we assume the .NET framework was tested) and saves us the time and pain of re-inventing the wheel.

Third, the code is easier to read, easier to understand, easier to change and so on. It is more maintainable.

Using classes with more refined functionality helps limit how we might screw up in using it.

On the whole your application is simply *better* when it's coded at appropriate levels of abstraction.

Stack is one of these classes.

**My HP-41X calculator does its arithmetic using a stack.** This way of calculation is called RPN - Reverse Polish Notation.

**If I were simulating a cafeteria the Stack would be perfect for that stack of plates.** Plates get on and off the stack from the top. Not the middle, not the end; just the top. A Stack. I can only Push() and Pop() plates which makes the code more simple and clear.

Alternatively, imagine coding with the C# equivalent of sub-atomic particles - generic collection or generic IEnumerable, etc. I end up using general utility methods and properties with general names with multi-variable numbers of parameters which in the aggregate obscure the fact that I'm stacking plates.

Comment: You just gave me a "Oh, now I got it!"-experience. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Ah, so another way to put it is to say it is a derivation of ICollection that provides fewer, more specific behaviors which are mostly modeled after a physical stack of something and subscribe to LIFO-style layering methods?

Answer (score 6):

[Depth first tree traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search). As opposed to a queue, for breadth first tree traversal.

---

Managing presenting different screens to a user as they navigate around them. Showing a screen pushes it to the stack, going 'back' pops it. Draw the top screen.

---

When you want a collection where you can add things and always know when you get something out it's the most recently added.

---

Implementing Undo/Redo functionality.

Comment: Also I believe it's what *insert pushy demographic here* use when joining a line.

Answer (score 4):

Depth First Search (DFS) is a good real-world example of the use of a stack.

http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~heap/270F02/node36.html

Answer (score 2):

If you do [expression evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29#Expression_evaluation_and_syntax_parsing) and syntax parsing, stack could be useful data structure.

Answer (score 2):

Heres one way I've used Stack:

I have a wizard like page where there are 5 user controls that need to be dispalyed and processed in a specific sequence, and the user should be able at any point to return to the last page in order.

I use a stack based state machine to track the users progress through the wizard.

Each time they move forward, I push the state of the state machine into a session stored stack, and if they request to go back, I pop off the top value and set the machine to the new top stack value. (Which in turn, displays and loads the proper control)

One more:

I had to build an install application for some very custom server applications. What I ended up doing was breaking each step of the install into its own generic component, ie, a component to copy a file, a component to write a registry value, ect. Each compontent had to methods: Do the install action, Undo the install action.

Each step of the install, the component is pushed into a stack.

Now, at any time I have an error, we just pop each component back off the stack, and run the undo action giving us fine grained install transactions.

Stack's are your friend!

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite recursive methods as iterative counterparts much easier by controlling the locals on and off the stack. Check out [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)'s sort using the stack [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/07/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-26d-fixing-the-key-selectors-and-yielding-early.aspx).

Comment: +1 for discussing the the general case.  I would add that this approach is helpful if you have a deeply recursive algorithm, because it allows you to recurse deeply without overflowing the call stack: `Stack<T>` instances are, of course, stored on the heap.

Answer (score 2):

stacks are useful when converting an expression from infix notation to prefix notation. For example:

`a + b` to `(+ a b)`

Answer (score 1):

Stack and Queue use internally an array. If you were using arrays in smart ways the chances are good that you have used them in a stack or queue like fashion already. Usually you need to decide between Stack and Queue. 
A typical example where a Stack is needed is [depth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). If you change the collection to a queue you have implemented a breadth first search.

Another example is heavy multithreading where you pass data between a producer and consumer via a stack if the processing order is not relevant. The rationale behind this is that if much data is going to be processed it is better for the CPU to use the latest added data chunk for further processing on the other thread to get better cache locality.

And the list goes on ....

Comment: I'm under the impression that stacks and queues are usually implemented with linked-lists.

Comment: At least the .NET BCL does implemenent Queue and Stack internally with arrays. Linked lists do not perform well in .NET due to the increased memory consumption and more complex object graph wich will make GCs more costly. With usually you mean C++ or ...? Since Stack and Queue are usually not used in a way to add or remove elements in the middle linked lists do make little sense there.

Answer (score 1):

Stacks are frequently used in text parsing algorithms, such as the evaluation of "4+5+6".  For a real-world example of an application that uses stacks to parse text, see [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).  This component is used to parse HTML, and it includes the source code, so you can see how and where stacks are used...

Answer (score 0):

I'd say if you were modeling something that is conceptually a stack.  Say you're modeling a small, but deep drawer and you're putting books in the drawer.  This will follow a "first in, last out" paradigm, which is the point of a stack in general.

You don't have a list of books or some kind of enumeration - you have a specific ordering of them... namely, the opposite of the order in which they were added.

Answer (score 0):

`Stack<T>`'s functionality really seems like a subset of `List<T>`(with a few renamed methods), so I agree it doesn't seem like the most useful collection by itself. When used internally in an algorithm, `List<T>` can easily substitute for it, even if that may be slightly less idiomatic.

Enforcing stack behavior is only necessary if it is exposed publicly. But it that case it's usually a better idea to expose some kind of wrapper over the internal collection, so it doesn't really seem very useful for that either.I'd certainly see use for a `IStack<T>` interface, but not so much for a plain collection class `Stack<T>`.

My conclusion is that I wouldn't have included a `Stack<T>` class in the framework, just a `IStack<T>` interface. The BCL collections generally don't look very well thought out to me.

`ConcurrentStack<T>` on the other hand seems much more useful.

Comment: If you were going to define an interface for `IStack<T>` wouldn't you include at least one class that implemented it? (i.e. the `Stack<T>` class).

Comment: @George I think that class would rather be a wrapper over another collection similar to `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`. Or would even be an explicit interface implementation on `List<T>`, or both.

Comment: Whether the `Stack<T>` is a wrapper or not is just an implementation detail. I'd definitely say getting List<T> to implement it would lead to a horrible class, I wouldn't really want Push and Pop methods on a list. I'd much rather have a `List<T>` for lists and a `Stack<T>` for stacks.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping track of Browser History is a use for the stack. Also, "undo" for edits, etc.
Similarly, some warehouse control systems use stacks and queues for managing the order in which items need to be selected for shipments.