# How do I know when to use a Stack instead of other Collections?

Tags: java, c#, stack

Here's a little prelude to the more general question I am wondering about:

I was recently doing a programming challenge where you are supposed to write a method that checks the balance of parentheses in a given String. The method was supposed to take in a String and return the index at which the  first extra ')' or '(' parentheses are, or the length of the String if they are equal. Some sample inputs would be like so: ")(asdf)))" - 0; "((((asdf)))" - 0; "((((asdf))" - 1; "(ab)(((cd)(asdf)" - 5.

I began by trying to create a List for each direction of parentheses which would store the indexes of all of them in the String. I would then go through each character in the String, add it's index to either list if it matched, and check to see if they had already mismatched. This strategy worked for some of the cases, but certain scenarios still failed. Feeling stuck, I checked some of the other answers on the challenge and saw them using a Stack to store the index of the left parentheses, which they would push to and pop from when necessary. This way worked much, much better, and I felt a little embarrassed for not thinking of it on my own.

This brings me to my question... how do I know when it is better to use a Stack over other various Collections? What are some common things that occur that could tip me off to use a Stack over any other Collection?

I know how Stacks work and have used them in some tutorials and such, but have never really found myself using them in the real world... which, after seeing the simplicity they created with the challenge, makes me think I have missed some opportunities to make simpler/better code.

Comment: Perhaps a bit too simple, but you use a stack anytime you have a LIFO processing requirement.

Comment: Right, basically anytime you find yourself working primarily with one "end" of a list.  This sort of thing ("how do I know to use X") becomes easier with experience.  You'll sort it out after you've had more examples to practice on.

Answer (score 2):

Like others have said, a Stack is used for when you need your collection to have Last In, First Out (LIFO) behavior. This can manifest whenever you are processing information on the "topmost" or "latest" of something.

The example you talked about was a great example of this, as to most effectively process parentheses groups, you store the left-parenthesis in a collection, and you remove the most recent left-parenthesis when you run into a right-parenthesis.

Stacks can also be used in certain tree/graph traversal algorithms. Depth-first approaches will use a Stack to store the list of nodes that still need to be traversed, as using a Stack combined with a consistent insertion pattern has the inherent property of searching trees' depth over their breadth. (The flipside of this is that breadth-first traversal algorithms use a Queue instead.)

Another possible use would be a deck of cards. For most games, you don't care about what's in the center of the deck somewhere. When the player needs a card, they just draw a card off the top. Since this mimics a Stack's behavior exactly, a Stack would be a possible consideration for this kind of application. (After all, a "deck" is just a stack of cards.)

There are a bunch of other applications as well. The thing they have in common is that they work for times when you want to need on either the topmost item or the most recent item of a collection. Knowing if your particular application would benefit from a Stack just takes a bit of experience in knowing how to recognize those scenarios.

*EDIT:* Oh, and of course there's ***the*** stack that .NET uses for method-scope and temporary variables. It's no coincidence that it shares its name with the data structure. When a variable is declared in a method, its memory allocation is added to the end of a stack. Then when the method returns and the variable goes out of scope, that memory is popped off the stack and handed to the garbage collector.

Answer (score 2):

Another good case for a stack is when you are entering some "context" that you will eventually leave. Even more so if you store some information that is only valid between the two moments and can be forgotten once you leave this "context".

In the parentheses example, you're "entering" whenever you match `(` and "leaving" the parentheses block upon matching `)`. While you are inside the parentheses, you need to remember the starting `(`'s position (in case it has no matching `)`), but once you find the matching `)` you can forget that info.

Answer (score 1):

When you need to working with LIFO (Last In First Out)
like when calling function or with postfix notation.

[You can see here more java examples!](http://people.cs.ksu.edu/~schmidt/300s05/Lectures/Week3.html)

Answer (score 0):

The following is the selected answer copied from the SO question: [When to use the Stack collection in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8765395/463206)

P.S. I am not plagiarizing. I wrote this answer.

---

Ideally you use, or create as needed, classes that reflect how things work in the real world, the things you are modeling in code. Such classes give us a level of abstraction so we can code in terms of what we are modeling/simulating. Additionally when coding some complex thing, using a familiar paradigm helps. To wit: Oh, this Fuzzinator class uses a Stack. I know what a stack is and how it works.

Second, that higher-level-of-abstraction class gives us code that works (we assume the .NET framework was tested) and saves us the time and pain of re-inventing the wheel.

Third, the code is easier to read, easier to understand, easier to change and so on. It is more maintainable.

Using classes with more refined functionality helps limit how we might screw up in using it.

On the whole your application is simply better when it's coded at appropriate levels of abstraction.

Stack is one of these classes.

**My HP-41X calculator does its arithmetic using a stack**. This way of calculation is called RPN - Reverse Polish Notation.

**If I were simulating a cafeteria the Stack would be perfect for that stack of plates**. Plates get on and off the stack from the top. Not the middle, not the end; just the top. A Stack. I can only Push() and Pop() plates which makes the code more simple and clear.

Alternatively, imagine coding with the C# equivalent of sub-atomic particles - generic collection or generic IEnumerable, etc. I end up using general utility methods and properties with general names with multi-variable numbers of parameters which in the aggregate obscure the fact that I'm stacking plates.